# Ocaml: calling recursive function again

Tags: printing, recursion, ocaml

So I have a recursive function that takes in 2 ints, and a out_channel and basically prints line(a,a+1). It should do this until value of a is equal to b. I.e if a = 1, b = 5

line(1,2)
line(2,3)
...line(4,5)

```
> let rec print_line (out:out_channel)(a:int)(b:int) : unit =
  if (a < b) then output_string out ("line("^string_of_int(a)^","^string_of_int(a+1)^")\n")
>    ;;
```

I want to make it recursive where it keeps printing the line(a,a+1) until a is no longer less than b. How exactly do I call it again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

So: first check whether `a >= b` in which case you are done and can return `()`. Otherwise print one line (the way you did) followed by recursive call to your function, with incremented `a`. So altogether:

```
let rec print_line (out:out_channel)(a:int)(b:int) : unit =
  if a >= b then
    ()
  else (
    output_string out ("line("^string_of_int(a)^","^string_of_int(a+1)^")\n");
    print_line out (a + 1) b
  )
```

Comment: note that you can actually use `let rec print_line out a b = ` as the first line, as the ocaml compiler is smart enough to know what the types of a b and out are.